# while download and delete file using laravel download pop up not coming

Tags: php, html, laravel

In my blade file i have attach one file to download by giving directly its path in  tag. While i  click on that link i have use ajax to remove that file from server,Now i can able to remove the file but i am not getting download-popup.Any one can help.
Thanks in advance.

blade file code

```
<a href="/temp/invalidData.csv" style="position: relative;padding-left: 20px" id="invalid">InvalidData.csv</a>
```

ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#invalid',function(){

        $.ajax({
              type:"post",
              url:'/delete-file',
              dataType:"json",
              success:function(data){
                if (data.type == "success") {

                        } else
                        {

                        }
                        return false;
        }
      });
        return false;
    });
});
```

controller code

```
public function deleteFile(){

        $file= public_path(). "/temp/invalidData.csv";

       return response()->download($file)->deleteFileAfterSend();


    }
```

Comment: You cannot use ajax to download a file, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970672/9193055).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple anchor tag to put a get call to download and delete file e.g.:

```
<a style="display: none;" href="address_for_request?file={{$file_path}}" id="path"  ></a>
```

then using jquery invoke a click event on anchor tag or make same process with ajax call :

```
 (function(){
   if(jQuery('#path').length) {
        jQuery('#path')[0].click();
   }
 })();
```

auto invoke explained here.

and in controller simple code to download:

```
      if ( isset( $request->file ) ) {
            session::forget('pdf');
            session::save();
            return response()->download(storage_path($request->file))->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
        }
```

Comment: now i face another problem , i can download and also delete file but the link for download is not remove from blade file , i need to reload the page.

Comment: For that purpose you can put path in session and get path in blade with condition and only render element if exists in session and after/during dowload function remove that from session and save new session. And it will work fine on reload. like in mycode in controller for session